# Weather conditions were bad enough or too bad even to give a pause to the most experienced climbers

Tags: phrase-choice

> 1. Weather conditions were **bad enough** even to give a pause to the most experienced climbers.
> 2. Weather conditions were **too bad** even to give a pause to the most experienced climbers.

I believe both *bad enough* and *too bad* are correct to say. But if I choose *bad enough* my answer is wrong. Is there any rule I can go through or it is just the way of saying so?

Answer (score 1):

Correct: "Weather conditions were **bad enough** to give pause to **even** the most experienced climbers."

Incorrect: "Weather conditions were **too bad** to give pause to **even** the most experienced climbers."

The incorrect sentence says that if the weather were *better* it would make the most experienced climbers stop and reconsider.

Correct:  "Weather conditions were **too bad** for even the most experienced climbers to leave their cabin."